# how many injective group homomorphisms from C3 to S5 are there

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How many injective group homomorphisms from $\phi: C_3\to S_5$ are there ?

Here $S_5$ is the symmetric group with 120 elements actually what is the this group $C_3$ how many elements does this group in general what is group called $C_n$ can any one explain about this problem

Comment: $C_n$ usually means the cyclic group with $n$ elements, also known as $\Bbb Z_n$ or $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Arthur....is exists any injective homomorphism from these groups

Comment: You should verify that this question is basically asking about the number of elements of order $3$ in $S_5$.

Comment: @MooS.. i think there 20 elements of order 3